# Changing Timeout on HttpClient of Microsoft.Owin.Testing.TestServer has no effect

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I am using .net 461, Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.2.3

```
var testServer = Microsoft.Owin.Testing.TestServer.Create<MyConfig>();

//this has no effect, and Timeout is still the default 100 seconds
testServer.HttpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(200);
```

If I do like this, then the setting takes effect:

```
var client = new HttpClient
{
   BaseAddress = new Uri("baseaddress")
};

client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(200); // this change has effect
```

Why can I not change the TimeOut property on the first snippet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn782655(v%3dvs.113)

> HttpClient
>   Returns a new HttpClient which wraps the Handler and is
>   capable of submitting requests to the OWIN pipeline.

So everytime you call `testServer.HttpClient`, a new `HttpClient` instance is created for you, that's why your change has no effect.